# When I use git stash I end up with <<<<<<< Updated upstream and other things in my files

Tags: git, merge

I am using GitHub desktop and git command line (to basically stash my code when I need to make a commit on another branch).  I use  `git stash save`
and save my code.  I then update another branch and switch back to my testing branch which i update to master.  I then unstash my code with
`git stash pop`

This is the output after I ran git stash pop:

```
Auto-merging update_registration.php 
CONFLICT (content):
Merge conflict in update_registration.php 
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.
```

But then I end up with

```
    <<<<<<< Updated upstream
    //Code and whatnot
    =======
    <<<<<<< Updated upstream
            
    >>>>>>> Stashed changes
```

in my files and it is quite frustrating truing to manage the code and delete all these lines from my code to upload it to the server.

Am I using git stash wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Actually you omitted the output of the command. Remember `git stash pop` does not restore the files you changed, but the changes you made. If the changes failed to apply (thus asking for messages), you need to merge them manually. That is what those `===`, `<<<` and `>>>` lines tell you.

Comment: @U.Windl  So should I use ```git stash apply```?  Right I do want to just restore the changes that I made before I left.  This is the output after I ran ```git stash pop: Auto-merging update_registration.php
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in update_registration.php
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.```  So I just need to figure out how to merge manually then?

Comment: (I added the command output from comment to the question, but formatting got lost; maybe fix it). Yes, you'll have to merge. I do it with my editor, searching for `====` lines. Then you have three choices: 1: Pick the variant above the line (between `<<<` and `===`), 2: Pick the variant below the line (between `===` and `>>>`), 3: Pick the one that mostly fits, making changes. In any case remove all those `<<<`, `>>>` and `===` lines. There are merge tools, but that's a different topic. Best try to minimize the need for merges.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What happened was this: You changed a part ("Updated upstream") while your changes were stashed that was also changed in the stashed part ("Stashed changes"). So when restoring the stashed changes, there was a merge conflict.

General advice: Do different things on different branches at different times, or do different things in different workspaces concurrently.
So if you are implementing something on branch `A` and you need to do something different on the project, and you have uncommitted changes, you have two choices:

1. Do it in the same workspace: Then do `git stash` saving your uncommitted changes, create a new branch (probably on `master`) with `git checkout -b <new_branch> master` or checkout an existing branch. Then hack along, committing changes, finally return to your work using `git checkout A` and `git stash pop`. Changes should apply cleanly then.
2. Do it in a different workspace: Do `git clone` of your repository in a different directory, hacking and comitting there. If you want to continue on the other branch, just change directories.

In any case you'll have to merge branches in the end if you want to integrate your work.  The better you organize your work, the more often you will pick option 1 from the list above.

Comment: actually, no. This is not only a result of "not organizing someone's work well". Github  Desktop shows a nasty habit of messing the code like this EVEN when there was NO change in the code, just switching between branches. Even though this is not an expected or uniform behaviour of Github  Desktop, it happens in once of XX cases, so one should be aware of this and backup the code that is stashed, bc. it messes it up quite badly ...

Answer (score 0):

This is not only a result of "not organizing someone's work well". Github  Desktop shows a nasty habit of messing with the code like this EVEN when there was NO change in the code, just switching between branches. Even though this is not an expected or uniform behavior of GitHub Desktop, it happens in one of XX cases, so one should be aware of this and back up the code that is stashed, bc. it messes it up quite badly ...

Comment: It might be a bug in git, too. Recently I had a case where both alternatives were identical, so I wondered why git could not resolve that "conflict".